# How can do I invoke a flow in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, lightning, lightning-experience

I have a Visual Workflow process which contain two screen elements.

I would like to know, how this flow could be invoked and to show the screen elements in a Lightning Component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (Spring 16) there is no support for Visual Workflow Screen elements in Lightning Components.

If you wanted a "Lightning UI" around flow, I have two suggestions:

First, use Visualforce and [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) to create a page that looks like Lightning Experience. You will probably have to do a little JS hacking on the rendered flow screens to change their classes and use the SLDS look and feel. But it is possible.

Second, you could use the Visualforce component in Lightning App Builder to pop your VF-wrapped-flow-screen into a common UI with other Lightning features, including the new Lightning Experience screens.